# Redis Lettuce Client Command Latency Event Wasn't Retrieved in the subscriber

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

##### Command latency event wasn't retrieved in the subscriber

The [code implementation](https://gist.github.com/varvay/a3caa2104709a2d7dfe868a682469d6f) of command latency monitoring using Letuce Redis client in Spring Boot MVC app didn't collecting any **command latency event**, only **connection event** recorded. Here's the log captured after the API that issue Redis command invoked,

Log Captured

```java
2023-10-15T15:43:06.116+07:00 INFO 30580 --- [xecutorLoop-3-2] c.m.redis.controller.Controller    : Log Event: ConnectedEvent [/<host>:<port> -> /<host>:<port>]
2023-10-15T15:43:06.167+07:00 INFO 30580 --- [xecutorLoop-3-3] c.m.redis.controller.Controller    : Log Event: ConnectionActivatedEvent [/<host>:<port> -> /<host>:<port>]
2023-10-15T15:43:06.303+07:00 INFO 30580 --- [xecutorLoop-3-4] c.m.redis.controller.Controller    : Log Event: ConnectedEvent [/<host>:<port> -> /<host>:<port>]
2023-10-15T15:43:06.377+07:00 INFO 30580 --- [xecutorLoop-3-5] c.m.redis.controller.Controller    : Log Event: ConnectionActivatedEvent [/<host>:<port> -> /<host>:<port>]
```

##### Input Code

Input Code

https://gist.github.com/varvay/a3caa2104709a2d7dfe868a682469d6f

##### Expected behavior/code

The **command latency event** captured in the log

##### Environment

- Lettuce version(s): 6.2.6.RELEASE
- Redis version: 6.2.10

##### Possible Solution

N/A

##### Additional context

N/A

##### GitHub Ticket

GitHub Ticket

https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/2523

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my exploration also supported by response in the GitHub Ticket, Micrometer won't emit latency event to Lettuce event bus. As workaround, I use  Lettuce `DefaultCommandLatencyCollector` instead of `MicrometerCommandLatencyRecorder`